# передача анонимной функции как аргумент

Tags: javascript, scope, область-видимости

**1**

```js
var a = 1;

function func(f) {
  var a = 2;

  function test(f) {
    f();
  }
  test(f);
}

func(function() {
  console.log(a);
});
```

**2**

```js
var a = 1;

function func() {
  var a = 2;

  function test(f) {
    f();
  }
  test(function() {
    console.log(a);
  });
}

func();
```

В первом примере, я вызываю функцию `func` с `анонимной функцией` в качестве `аргумента`, и в последствии передаю его(`аргумент`) в вызов функции `test`.
Во втором примере уже передаю `анонимную функцию` в качестве `аргумента` на прямую функции `test`.

Все эти манипуляции я делал для того, что бы понять, в какой `области видимости` была создана `анонимная функция`.

> При создании функция получает скрытое свойство `[[Scope]]`, которое
>   ссылается на лексическое окружение, в котором она была создана.

Меня интересует вопрос, почему у `анонимной функции` `[[Scope]]` равен той `области видимости`, в которой она была передана в качестве `аргумента` другой функции? Я предполагал что `[[Scope]]` у нее(`анонимной функции`) будет равен функции, в которую мы передали в качестве `аргумента` нашу `анонимную функцию`.

Answer (score 0):

Область видимости анонимной функции-аргумента не может быть областью видимости той функции, куда мы ее передаем. Функция, куда передаем, ничего не знает о функции-аргументе кроме сигнатуры последней. А функция-аргумент знает о коде, который ее будет вызывать, еще меньше. Мне кажется, Вы думаете, что функция-аргумент передается как текст исходного кода. Это не так. Она передается как ссылка на объект, который приносит с собой (в виде замыкания) все внешние переменные необходимые для выполнения, а не ищет переменные с таким названием в области видимости того места, где функция-аргумент вызывается (а вдруг их там нет?).

Об анонимности. Принципиальной разницы между

```
var a = 1;

function func(f) {
  f();
}

func(function() {
  console.log(a);
});
```

и

```
var a = 1;

function func(f) {
  f();
}

function aaa() {
  console.log(a);
} 
func(aaa);
```

нет.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71306/discussion-on-answer-by-igor-----).

Comment: @NickVolynkin я не владею такими привилегиям для создания чата.

Answer (score -1):

Начнем по порядку.

Вы в обоих примерах в функциях `func` и `test` передаете параметр анонимную функцию. Но что делают ваши анонимные функции? (просто лог).

> Они не возвращают ничего. То есть ваши эти две функции не получают не
>   какого параметра.

Скажу так глобальная область видимости доступна всем. Потому в первом примере у вас лог `1`.

А во втором видно глобальная, но анонимная функция здесь поскольку объявлено в функции с именем `func`, Ему доступны и глобальные переменные внутри `func`. То есть `var a = 2`.

Comment: 1. _Вы в обоих примерах в функциях func и test передаете параметр анонимную функцию._ Может передаю анонимную функцию в качестве аргумента ?
2. _Они не возвращают ничего. То есть ваши эти две функции не получают не какого параметра._ Функции при вызове передают аргумента, а параметры задают при объявлении функции. Я дальше не осилил, ибо написано ужасно. Отредактируйте ответ, или напишите новый.